# How to add click event to array of buttons?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

How to add click event to my array of buttons?

I need just 1 click event that will work the same way for each button.

```
ButtonArray[i] = new Button();
ButtonArray[i].Margin = new Thickness(horizontal, vertical, 0, 0);
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(ButtonArray[i]);
ButtonArray[i].Height = buttonsize;
ButtonArray[i].Width = buttonsize;
ButtonArray[i].Background = brush;
ButtonArray[i].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
ButtonArray[i].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
ButtonArray[i].Click += ButtonArray_Click;
```

Then:

```
void ButtonArray_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //Do your stuff
}
```